# sed won't replace text

Tags: shell, sed

I have this text file (wget.log):

```
1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5% 78.5K 4m10s
  1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5% 46.6K 4m19s
  1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  5%  105K 4m17s
  1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  6% 63.0K 4m21s
  1600K ..........
```

Since I just want to replace the `..........` in the last 3 lines. I tried this command:

```
tail -n 3 /www/wget.log | sed 's/. /=>/g'
```

but it won't replace anything. I want the output to be like this:

```
1500K => 5%  105K 4m17s
1550K => 5%  105K 4m17s
1600K =>
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below sed command.

```
$ tail -n 3 /www/wget.log | sed 's/ \..*\.\( \|$\)/ => /g'
  1500K =>  5%  105K 4m17s
  1550K =>  6% 63.0K 4m21s
  1600K =>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
tail -n 3 /www/wget.log | sed -r 's/(\.+ *)+/=> /'
1500K => 5%  105K 4m17s
1550K => 6% 63=> 0K 4m21s
1600K =>
```

On OSX use:

```
tail -n 3 /www/wget.log | sed -E 's/(\.+ *)+/=> /'
```